# User input in a name field, future negative consequenses if not validated?

Tags: java, validation, user-input

I am making a little game and it requires that the user enter their name. The code snippet that requires it is as follows:

```
System.out.printf("What do you wish to be called: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
```

Throughout the program, the user's "name" may be used to reference them, as it will be outputted various times.

I currently do not have the program validate what the user enters so whatever they type will be used as their name. For example, if they set their name as "E3 CP Beta" then I might have some code like:

```
System.out.println("Would you look at that, " + name + " finally got here");
```

Which would result in "Would you look at that, E3 CP Beta finally got here.

Now my question is, could this have some negative impact in the long run and should I add a validation so that they can't bypass anything later? I mean of course it depends on how I choose to use their input but since it is a name, it will be used quite often.

Comment: "could this have some negative impact" of course it *could*.

Comment: can you come up with one single example of how a name would cause negative impact? except for the possibility that there are multiple users and they enter the exact same name, I can't really think of one

Comment: But: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: How would you define a "valid" name? We can't really tell what problem it would cause without knowing what you're doing with that name. If you store it in a database column which has a max length of 30, for example, then you should validate that the name is less than 30 characters long.

Comment: @AndyTurner nice list of rules, but at first glance I've already spotted a few things that are simply not true. since we don't know what is considered 'valid' (and as I read the post, everything is), I don't see any impact at all

Comment: @Stultuske I can imagine there being a problem if, say, you naively try to parse the name out of a string, and the tokens of that name look somewhat like other tokens embedded in the string.

Comment: This is what I mean by it: I'm studying for my Security+ exam and in the book I'm reading it gives an example of a "Cross-Site Scripting" (XSS) attack in which it relies on user input not being validated, and that input being used in a response. So what I want to know is if that same sort of thing could be done on here through java, and if so, how could I re-create my code to avoid that.

Comment: @AndyTurner considering the examples provided, he's not trying to do anything as such. next of: if you yourself decide on "part1 " + name + " part2", you know what part1 and part2 are, so there is no problem parsing it (especially since you have the name already in a separate variable)

Comment: @Stultuske everything on that list is wrong: "All of these assumptions are wrong". That's kinda the point of the article...

Comment: @Paul the code you posted has nothing whatsoever to do with "Cross-Site Scripting". How do you imagine something like that happening in stand-alone code that runs in a separate vm?

Comment: What I wanted to know was if there was something similar to (XSS) that could be done in java, if the user could enter some form of anything, so that they could bypass something in the program.

Comment: Besides, XSS is not really about validating input. It's about properly escaping it when rendered in a HTML page.

Comment: @AndyTurner how do you consider #2 to be false?

Comment: @Paul sure, that can happen. But it's not really related to Java. It's related to a stupid thing you would do with the name. Like, for example, let the user enter a name, and using it as a command you would execute on the computer. Then sure, if I enter `;rm -rf /` as my name, and you programmatically  execute that as a command, you'll have a problem. But it's not about the name. It's about not doing stupid things (just like XSS).

Comment: @JB Alright that clarifies it up for me, thank you

Comment: @Paul https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Stultuske #2 is false for any professional who practises under a different name from their legal name. In the UK, it is common for female doctors and lawyers to practise under their maiden name (under which they qualified), but otherwise be known by their married name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of simply assigning an input to name variable, you could create an appropriate class and provide something like `setName(String name)` method in this class. In body of this method you could do all the validations needed for your code, for example check if the name passed to this method as argument hasn't been used by someone else before (you would need to check if a `List` storing Player's names already contains exactly the same name). But you can perform all other checks you just know that should be included there.

The part of the code that asks for input, could be enclosed in some kind of loop, checking if the typed name has been used already or if it meets your other requirements. If it is ok, it breaks the loop then.

Anyway, I think that to make all the validations, calling an appropriate method instead of simply assigning an input to a variable seems to be a much better idea.